# Статическое подменю

Tags: asp.net, c#

Начал сейчас заниматься сайтом на `asp.net`. В студии создал проект, там есть "Мастер Страниц", который содержит постоянные ссылки на страницы. Теперь мне надо, чтобы такая же статическая страница было уже во внутреннем окне, т.е. чтобы можно было переходить по страницам раздела.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете нужные вам страницы и наследуете их от данной мастер страницы (это делается при создании новой страницы, либо в старой прописать в блоке page masterpagefile="~/Main.master"). После чего поменять ссылку в мастер странице на вашу новую ссылку страницу(либо создавать новые страницы уже с требуемым названием, т.е. те которые у вас в мастер странице).